# Obfuscating Android library project, when aspectj used

Tags: android, obfuscation, proguard

I have Android library project. There are some .aj files (aspectJ) with pointcuts.
I need to obfuscate compiled artifact (jar). When i obfuscate it and add as library to another project, aspects stops working.
Can anyone help with obfuscation using ProGuard? Some configuration examples or any useful information.
May be it is not possible at all? Are there some alternatives?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I also have an android library with aspects. My pointcuts are not for my library code, but for the app's code (pointcuts on Activity.onCreate, for example), so people who use my library are already expected to set up their android projects as AspectJ projects.

Everything works perfectly without Proguard, but despite making every exception I can think of I couldn't get the advice to apply if my library jar was obfuscated. I verified that the aspect class and all methods and fields were kept in the mapping.

Here's the final version of my proguard config that didn't get the aspects working, although everything compiles fine and there are no errors:

```
...some config, the injar included my iajc compiled library project with aspects

-optimizations !code/allocation/variable,!code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*
-optimizationpasses 3
-dontpreverify
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers
-verbose

-keepattributes Exceptions,InnerClasses,Signature,Deprecated,
                SourceFile,LineNumberTable,*Annotation*,EnclosingMethod

# This is the package of my aspects
-keep class my.package.aspectj.** { *; }
# This is all the public methods that my aspect code calls in to
-keep class my.package.allthethingsmyaspectscall.** { *; }

 ...keep some other classes not related to this
```

With all this my aspects still didn't apply.

**My solution was to copy my aspect files into the client app's project at install time so that it is in their app classpath and gets woven when their app gets built.**